# Why Derrived pointer binds statically to Derived object meanwhile a Base pointer binds dynamically to Base object?

Tags: c++, class, virtual, dynamic-binding, static-binding

In the attached code why:
p1->print(); binds dynamically?
and why:
p2->print();
binds statically ?

```
#include<iostream>

class Base{   public:

virtual void print() 
{     std::cout<<"Base"<<std::endl;}  
    
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:

virtual void print()
{    std::cout<<"Derived"<<std::endl; }  
};
int main()
{
    Base *p1 = new Base{ } ;
     
    p1->print();
     
    std::cout<<"------------------"<<std::endl; 
    Derived *p2 = new Derived{ } ;    
   
    p2->print();
    
    return 0;
}
```

According to my knowledge a virtual functions binds dynamically if the pointer or reference is of type different than the object type being pointed to by the pointer or reference AND there must be a virtual function to activate dynamic binding.

Comment: A virtual function is *always* called with dynamic lookup, at least conceptually (a compiler may of course call directly or even inline if it can prove that's the correct function). The dynamic lookup will always call the function definition in the actual object referred to, independent of the pointer or reference type. The two may be the same, then that's what's being called. No surprise there.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that one binds dynamically and the other binds statically? (I would expect the same behavior in either case in your example since the pointer types match the object types.) You could answer this by editing your question to add the output you'd expect if both bound dynamically and the output you'd expect if both bound statically. Then to complete the picture, add the output you actually get.

Comment: It is not me who concluded, it is the online instructor, he said in the video p1->print( ); binds dynamically, and this really confused me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `print` is searched in the classes according to the static types of the pointers

```
Base *p1 = new Base{ } ;
 
p1->print();
 
Derived *p2 = new Derived{ } ; 

p2->print();
```

As the static type of the pointer `p1` is `Base *` when the function `print` is searched in the class `Base`.

On the other hand, as the static type of the pointer `p2` is `Derived *` then the function `print` is searched in the class `Derived`.

You could write for example

```
Base *p3 = new Derived{};

p3->print();
```

in this case as the static type of the pointer `p3` is `Base *` then the function `print` will be searched in the class `Base`. But as the dynamic type of the pointer is `Derived *` then the function `print` of the derived class will be called.

Consider the following demonstration program

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void print() const
    {
        std::cout << "Base\n";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
    void print() const override
    {
        std::cout << "Derived\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base *p1 = new Derived();

    p1->print();

    Derived *p2 = new Derived();

    // compilation error: private function is inaccessible
    // p2->print();

    delete p1;
    delete p2; 
}
```

The program output is

```
Derived
```

As you can see though in the class `Derived` the function is private nevertheless it is called for the pointer `p1` because the pointer static type is `Base *` and within the class `Base` the function is public.

However if you will try to call the function using the pointer `p2` having the static type `Derived *` then the compiler will issue an error because the function within the class `Derived` is private that is inaccessible.

Comment: But the function is **not** searched according to the pointer type! What gets called is always the implementation in the type that the actual object *pointed to* has.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica  A virtual function is searched according to the static type of a pointer and the demonstration program in the answer shows that. That is the name lookup is performed according to the static type of a pointer.

Comment: ok, yes, the lookup, yes. the dynamic "search" not. I got confused because you answer something the OP didn't ask, I think ;-).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica There is no "dynamic search". There is dynamic binding.

Comment: There is even less a static "search" ;-).

Comment: I think the answer could be improved by using "lookup" instead of "search", and by distinguishing between the *declaration* which is used to look up the function at compile time, and the *definition* of a function which is used at run time.

Comment: Thank you guys, much respect, to be frank I am still learning and I need little time to fully grasp the answers, much love :)

Answer (score 1):

Both calls *are* dynamically bound it just makes no difference in your example.

Dynamic binding means that a call will be resolved based on the dynamic, runtime type of the object pointed to rather than the static type of the pointer pointing to it.  In your example, however, both of those types are the same, so the result will be identical.

Dynamic binding only comes into play when the static type of the object is *different* from the type of the pointer pointing to it.  For example:

```
Base* p3 = new Derived{};
p3->print();
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49898146114c72ce)

This will print "Derived" even though the static type of `p3` is `Base*` because the dynamic type of the object pointed to is `Derived`.

Comment: Base * p4 = new Base { } ;                                                                                                              p4->print( ) ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             this is dynamic binding even though both static and dynamic types are match , why ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at.  You already covered that case in your original example.  It's dynamically bound because `print` is declared `virtual` and called via a pointer or reference.  The dynamic dispatch finds `Base::print` because that's the runtime type of the object pointed to.